# Get Last Inserted ID in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm new to Laravel.. 
How to Get a Last inserted Id In Laravel model Form.

When Creating a New Project Auto Display the project code from Database

Last Inserted ID + 1 ;

```
{{ Form::text('project_code', Input::old('name'), array('class' => 'form-control','disabled')) }}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel, get last insert id using Eloquent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084833/laravel-get-last-insert-id-using-eloquent)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We'll need to see your code to be sure, but if you're using eloquent, then when you insert it into the database using `$model->save()`, then `$model->id` should have the inserted id.

so

```
$model = new Model();

$model->field = $var;
$model->field = $var;
$model->field = $var;

$model->save();

$insert_id = $model->id;
```