# How to get last insert id in Eloquent ORM laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am performing a database operation with "Eloquent ORM in Laravel". I just want to take the last insert id (not the maximum id) in the database.

I searched to get last insert id in laravel Eloquent ORM, I got following link ([Laravel, get last insert id using Eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21084833/2960703)) that is refer to get last insert id from following function "`$data->save()`".

But I need to get

"`Model::create($data)`";

**My Query:**

```
GeneralSettingModel::create($GeneralData);

User::create($loginuserdata);
```

How can I retrieve the last inserted id?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel, get last insert id using Eloquent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084833/laravel-get-last-insert-id-using-eloquent)

Comment: If `If the table has an auto-incrementing id` Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46482971/2815635

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Like the docs say: [Insert, update, delete](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#insert-update-delete)

> "You may also use the create method to save a new model in a single
>   line. **The inserted model instance will be returned to you from the
>   method**. However, before doing so, you will need to specify either a
>   fillable or guarded attribute on the model, as all Eloquent models
>   protect against mass-assignment.
>
> **After saving or creating a new model that uses auto-incrementing IDs,
>   you may retrieve the ID by accessing the object's id attribute:**"

```
$insertedId = $user->id;
```

So in your sample:

```
$user = User::create($loginuserdata);
$insertedId = $user->id;
```

then on table2 it is going to be

```
$input['table2_id'] = $insertedId;
table2::create($input);
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the doc is misleading because the first method shown is `->save();` and it doesnt, IMO, do enough to explain that `save()` returns a boolean while *only* Insert, update, and delete return the instance. Especially since in says "After **saving** or creating"

Answer (score 22):

**** For Laravel ****

```
$user = new User();

$user->name = 'John';

$user->save();

//Getting Last inserted id

$insertedId = $user->id;
```

Comment: $lastInsertedID = DB::table('users')
                     ->insert( array(
                                   'email_id' => $email_id,
                                   'name' => $name
                               )
                     )
                    ->lastInsertId();

Comment: Thanks for answer but I solved my issue. It's about primaryKey. I was changed primarkey in Model. So I didnt get last id. After change primarykey to id, it worked.

Comment: Thanks for your response

Answer (score 6):

You could wrap your data in the insertGetId() method like this

```
$id = DB::table('table')->insertGetId( $data );
```

In this case the array $data would look something like this

```
$data = [ 'field' => 'data' , 'field' => 'data' ];
```

and  if you’re using the DB façade you could just append the lastInsertID() method to your query.

```
$lastInsertedID = DB::table('table')->insert( $data )->lastInsertId();
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `insertGetId` only works if the column is actually named `id`.

Answer (score 3):

```
$lastId = User::create($loginuserdata)->id;
```

Answer (score 2):

As others said bfore me you may retrieve id by using

```
$model->id;
```

but only if you are using standard naming convention for eloquent. If you want to use other name for primaryKey column, eg:

```
class Users extends Model{
    $primaryKey = 'userid';
}
```

you may retrieve last inserted id by calling

```
$model->userid;
```

It is described in: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions where one can find:

> Eloquent will also assume that each table has a primary key column
>   named id. You may define a $primaryKey property to override this
>   convention.
>
> In addition, Eloquent assumes that the primary key is an incrementing
>   integer value, which means that by default the primary key will be
>   cast to an int automatically. If you wish to use a non-incrementing or
>   a non-numeric primary key you must set the public $incrementing
>   property on your model to false.

Comment: Dear @Krzysiek Grzembski I need it in my controller.I changed it in the model as you written it in the model.But now $model->userid; is where accessible.I need it in my controller.Please guide...

Comment: @Raham Please see my updated answear. It is hard to tell what is your problem without any piece of code.

Comment: actually I solved my problem.My problem was that how can I retrieve the last inserted one from table.Now I looked up for your answer that how you return the last inserted one.where you defined $model...

Comment: The problem is the trigger generated keys

Answer (score 2):

You may do it as,

```
public function store(Request $request,ModelName $obj)
{
        $lastInsertedId = $obj->create($request->all())->id;

}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

This is an eloquent model:

```
$user = new Reports();        
$user->email= 'david@example.com';  
$user->save();
$lastInsertId = $user->id;
```

A solution using Query Builder:

```
 $lastInsertId = DB::table('reports')->insertGetId(['email' => 'david@example.com']);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my try:

```
$model_ins = Model::orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(1)->first();
```

And use `$model_ins->id`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$user = (new user)->create($request->all()) ;

        \Session::flash('message', 'Thanks , Your record No (' .$user->id . ') has been Successfully added');
```

This is my solution. I return the inserted object and get its ID or any other property.

Answer (score 1):

This code works with Laravel 5.3:

```
$upstatus = User::create($status);
return response()->json($upstatus);
```

User pages/site I was call `data.id`

Answer (score 1):

This is an easier way that works on all of the ways that you inserted:

```
DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId()
```