# Retrieve last inserted Id. Laravel

Tags: mysql, insert, laravel-5

I want to retrieve last inserted id from my table students and pass to view. But i don't know how to? I have used following code for inserting data inside my table.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $input=Request::all();

        Student::create($input);
        $students=Student::all();
        $M_fees=M_fees::all();
        return view('students.fees',compact('students','M_fees'));

    }
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27873777/how-to-get-last-insert-id-in-eloquent-orm-laravel

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked!

Answer (score 0):

Actually its figured out!
Just store the model in a variable like:

```
  $student= Student::create($input);
        $students=Student::all();
        $insertedId= $student->id;
        return $insertedId;
```

It works pretty well!