# How to get last inserted id in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Here is my code

```
 $users = DB::table('users')->insert(array(
     'email_id' => $email_id,
     'name' => $name,
 ));

 $lastInsertedID = $users->lastInsertId();
           
 return $lastInsertedID;
```

I want to get last inserted id for particular record. I have tried using Eloquent ORM. but it didn't work.

Any help would be grateful.

Thank You.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084833/laravel-get-last-insert-id-using-eloquent   and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27873777/how-to-get-last-insert-id-in-eloquent-orm-laravel  and   http://smileyhappycoder.co.uk/server-side/fetching-last-insert-id-laravel/

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use [insertGetId()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#inserts)

```
$id = DB::table('users')-> insertGetId(array(
    'email_id' => $email_id,
    'name' => $name,
));
```

Answer (score 3):

**Follow the code to get last inserted id by using ->insert()**

```
$lastInsertedID = DB::table('users')
                     ->insert( array(
                         'email_id' => $email_id,
                         'name' => $name
                         )
                     )
                    ->lastInsertId();
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are the following methods to get `last inserted id`

## Eloquent

#### Method 1

```
$user = new User();
$user->name = "Test";
$user->save();
dd($user->id);
```

#### Method 2

```
$user = User::create(['name' => 'Test']);
dd($user->id);
```

## Query Builder

#### Method 3

In this method **Primary Key** must me `id`. If its other then `id` for example `some_id` then this method will **throw exception**.

```
$id = DB::table('users')->insertGetId(['name' => 'Test']);
dd($id);
```

#### Method 4

This method is usefull if you are using **DB Facade** and have **Custom Primary Key** like `some_id`.

```
DB::table('users')->insert(['name' => 'Test']);
dd(DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId());
```

Answer (score 1):

$id = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();

Comment: This worked like a charm right after my Eloquent ModelName:create method! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you inserted record id?
You can get the following way:

**//UserController.php**

```
$user  = new User;
$user->name = $request->name;
$user->email = $request->email;
if($user->save()){
    echo "User's record id is ".$user->id; *//$user->id is your lastest record id*
}
```