# getting id of most recent inserted row of table on laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

Suppose I have just inserted row on table `test` as like `Test::create($inputs);`,which has auto increment primary key field `id`.How to get id of row that I have just inserted using laravel 4.2/5 ?

Comment: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084833/laravel-get-last-insert-id-using-eloquent

Comment: @jewelhuq ,this uses save() method which needs to set value for each field one by one.However I want to use create() method to insert that takes array of inputs at once to insert data and get recently inserted row's id

Comment: You may try DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following snippet:

```
$test = Test::create($inputs)
```

Will enable you to use `$test->id`.

Answer (score 0):

**You can get the inserted id by using the example**

```
$inserted_id = Test::create($inputs)->id;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following line to fetch last insert id while save

after save the record you need to use **$test->id;**

Comment: Your answer is very confusing. Please consider editing using a more clear way of expressing your suggestion.