# Query builder not inserting timestamps

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-builder

I am using Query builder to insert data all fields are been inserted but timestamps like created_at and updated_at are not inserting they all have default 0:0:0 values 
my insert query is

```
$id = DB::table('widgets')
            ->insertGetId(array(
                'creator' => Auth::user()->id,
                'widget_name' => $request->input('widget_name'),
                'pages' => json_encode($request->input('pages')),
                'domain' => $request->input('domain'),
                "settings" => $settings,
            ));
```

Answer (score 86, accepted):

All right. Fields `created_at`,`update_at` and `deleted_at` are "part" of `Eloquent`. You use `Query Builder`=> inserting doesn't affect on these two fields (`created_at` and `updated_at`). You should define it manually like:

```
$id = DB::table('widgets')
        ->insertGetId(array(
            'creator' => Auth::user()->id,
            'widget_name' => $request->input('widget_name'),
            'pages' => json_encode($request->input('pages')),
            'domain' => $request->input('domain'),
            "settings" => $settings,
            "created_at" =>  \Carbon\Carbon::now(), # new \Datetime()
            "updated_at" => \Carbon\Carbon::now(),  # new \Datetime()
        ));
```

Comment: isn't there any way by which it can be done automatically

Comment: @Samundra KC do you want use only QueryBuilder?

Comment: Use Laravel Macros: https://medium.com/fattihkoca/laravel-auto-save-timestamps-with-query-builder-without-using-eloquent-123f7ebfeb92

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I'm using `date('Y-m-d H:i:s');` to get current dateTime. It works every time.

```
    $id = DB::table('widgets')
        ->insertGetId(array(
            'creator' => Auth::user()->id,
            'widget_name' => $request->input('widget_name'),
            'pages' => json_encode($request->input('pages')),
            'domain' => $request->input('domain'),
            "settings" => $settings,
            "created_at" =>  date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            "updated_at" => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        ));
```

Comment: "It works every time" - as long as you have an equal timezone in the DB and PHP ;)

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use raw expression and 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' as the value assuming the database is a MySQL database.

```
$now = DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP');
$rowID = DB::table('user')->insertGetId([
  'name' => $request->name,
  'updated_at' => $now,
  'created_at' => $now
]);
```

Comment: This answer is the fastest. When you're mass assigning, Carbon::now() is slower. 110k rows is 15 seconds faster. Thanks!

Comment: @PhillipMcCubbin if you call Carbon::now() on each of those 110k records, it's understandable that it's much slower. If you call Carbon::now() once and then use that value for those 110k records, it shouldn't matter.