# How to insert a value to created_at field using Query Builder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel. I am looking for a way to insert a value to specific field such as `created_at` automatically whenever the row is inserted to the DB table.

I found out that only `Eloquent` way which uses `some Model->save()` inserts timestamp to desired field.

But I want to be able to insert a value even when I use QueryBuilder. Is there any way to do so?

I have looked at this post: [Query builder not inserting timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33452124/query-builder-not-inserting-timestamps)

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you want to acheave ?

Comment: Why dont you set up a trigger in the database instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've [said before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47989148/custom-created-at-and-use-only-custom-created-at) you're using `Model::insertGetId()`, but the thing is this method is not using Eloquent. It's a Query Builder method. So, use `create()` instead:

```
$object = Model::create($data);
$id = $object->id;
```

If you still want to use `insertGetId()`, you'll need to add `created_at` timestamp manually:

```
$data['created_at'] = now();
Model::insertGetId($data);
```

Or you could set `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as a default for timestamp column, but it's so much better to just use Eloquent to handle this.

Comment: $data['created_at'] = now();

Answer (score -1):

You can make a new helper methods in helpers.php
Something like this:

```
public function queryBuilderInsert($table, $data, $deleted_at = false)
    {
        $data['created_at'] = \Carbon::now();
        $data['updated_at'] = \Carbon::now();
        $deleted_at ? $data['deleted_at'] = null :;

        \DB::table($table)->insert($data);
    }
public function queryBuilderUpdate($builder, $data)
    {
        $data['updated_at'] = \Carbon::now();
        $builder->update($data);
    }
```

And then you can build your queries like this:

For `insert` use `queryBuilderInsert` method

```
$example_data = [
    'name' => 'Name',
    'email'=> 'Email'
];
queryBuilderInsert('users',$example_data);
```

If you're using soft deletes on your table you can use the third parameter of `queryBuilderInsert`

```
queryBuilderInsert('users',$example_data, true);
```

For `update`, you can make your query and then call `queryBuilderUpdate` method

```
$example_update_data = [
    'name' => 'Name',
    'email'=> 'Email'
];
$builder = \DB::table('users')->where('id',1);
queryBuilderUpdate($builder,$example_update_data);
```

It will set `updated_at` date and make update