# How to get last inserted auto-incremented id and insert it into another table in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, phpmyadmin, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have journallog and subjournallog tables. When I insert data in the journallog table, I'd like to get the auto-incremented id from it and insert into the  subjournallog table.  Can someone provide an example of how to do this?

Comment: `$user = User::create(['emai' => 'EMAIL', 'password' => 'PASSWORD']);` creates the user and returns it. And I think that `ID` is accessible via `$user->id`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel, get last insert id using Eloquent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084833/laravel-get-last-insert-id-using-eloquent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$user = User::create(['emai' => 'EMAIL', 'password' => 'PASSWORD']);`

creates the user and returns it. 
And `ID` is accessible via `$user->id`