# Laravel get id of latest inserted user

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I'm using the Laravel Auth to make users able to register. What I'm now trying is: After users register (if they have a special role selected), there is another row inserted into another table (then users) which holds the relating user id. This is the code for it:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use App\Complaint;


class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
            'username' => 'required|unique:users',
            'role' => 'required'
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {

        $user = new User;
        $user->name = $data['name'];
        $user->email = $data['email'];
        $user->username = $data['username'];
        $user->password = bcrypt($data['password']);
        $user->role = $data['role'];
        $user->templateURL = "";

        /*$user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'role' => $data['role'],
            'templateURL' => ""
        ]);*/

        $user->save();


        if($data['role'] == 'Verkäufer'){
            $complaintRow = Complaint::create([
               'user_id' => $user->id,
                'complaintCount' => 0
            ]);
        }


        switch($data['role']){
            case 'Käufer':
                $user->attachRole(2);
                break;
            case 'Verkäufer':
                $user->attachRole(3);
                break;
            default:
                $user->attachRole(2);
                break;
        }


        return $user;
    }
}
```

But it's not working correctly, the user is inserted as well as a row for the complaints, but somehow `$user->id` seems to be null, the column always has `user_id` set to 0. Any ideas why this could be like this?

**EDIT**: I got it working now... It was actually not the code I posted, I just didn't make the `user_id` field fillable in the `complaint` table, that's why there was 0 in always, because 0 was the default value, so it just didn't set it.

Thanks all for the answers anyway.

Answer (score 2):

As per Laravel Eloquent ORM, `$user->id` will return the Id of user.
If you are getting null, then there might be error in saving. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/21084888/6628079)

Try printing `$user` after saving it.

**UPDATE:**
It would be better if you add data in complaint table if user is saved successfully.

```
protected function create(array $data)
{

    $user = new User;
    $user->name = $data['name'];
    $user->email = $data['email'];
    $user->username = $data['username'];
    $user->password = bcrypt($data['password']);
    $user->role = $data['role'];
    $user->templateURL = "";

    /*$user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'role' => $data['role'],
        'templateURL' => ""
    ]);*/

    if ($user->save()) {
        if ($data['role'] == 'Verkäufer') {
            $complaintRow = Complaint::create([
                'user_id' => $user->id,
                'complaintCount' => 0
            ]);
        }


        switch ($data['role']) {
            case 'Käufer':
                $user->attachRole(2);
                break;
            case 'Verkäufer':
                $user->attachRole(3);
                break;
            default:
                $user->attachRole(2);
                break;
        }


        return $user;
    } else {
        // Your code if user doesn't save successfully.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because, `Eloquent` save method `bool` but not the instance of newly created Entity. For confirmation checkout this link: https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html

So, if you want to get the newly created instance you can either user create method or make another query to get newly inserted instance. First one is better ans easy. Here is how you can do it:

```
$user = User::create([
    'name' => $data['name'],
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'username' => $data['username'],
    'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    'role' => $data['role'],
    'templateURL' => ""
]);
```

Now, you have `$user` variable containing `User` instance. But to do this you need to consider fillable/guared issue in your model. I mean, in your model you have to add the following line:

```
protected $fillabe = ['name', 'email', 'username', 'password', 'role', 'templateURL']
```

Comment: yeah, thats the code I have commented out in the code I provided, this ends in the same problem...

Comment: But somehow, the fillable helped me to get the problem (even if it wasn'T about the `User` model

Answer (score 1):

Is column `id` exists? 
Try to set `$primaryKey = 'id'` on model (user).

After `$user->save` you can access to `id` like `$user->id`
Or after `$user->save` try to get max id from your table.

```
$user = User::select('id')->max('id')->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$lastId = User::create($userData)->id;
```

Answer (score 0):

`$user->id` will tell you created user's ID right after using `save()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You did all most correct you just need to change,

> when you are **saving user object it will return saved user object** so just grab that object and use in furcher conditions.

```
$saved_user = $user->save();

if(!empty($saved_user)){
      if($data['role'] == 'Verkäufer')
        {
                    $complaintRow = Complaint::create([
                       'user_id' => $saved_user->id,
                        'complaintCount' => 0
                    ]);
                }
  } else {
     throw new error(500);

}
```

Hope this will help thanks :)

Comment: @nameless try to wrap if condition for $saved_user so that we can know that user is saving properly. may be you have error in saving user not in getting id.

Comment: @nameless can you please show us your database table structure. and User class