# How to get last inserted id through save() method in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I know to get the last id I can use `insertGetId()` but I want to know how can I get the last inserted id through `save()` method.

```
order = new Store_order;
    $order->invoice_id = $signed['invoice_id'];
    $invoice = $order->save()['so_id'];
```

I used this but it returns `null` value

Comment: why do not you use relationships?

Comment: I know how to do it with relations. I want to know with `save()` method!

Comment: In all cases, when you save, it will not return an invoice object. Which id are you looking for? Order Id?

Comment: `so_id` is the PRIMARY KEY and AUTO_INCREMENT in database structure. So I want to get that `so_id`

Comment: This post may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084833/laravel-get-last-insert-id-using-eloquent

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel, get last insert id using Eloquent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084833/laravel-get-last-insert-id-using-eloquent)

Answer (score 10):

After `$order->save()`, `$order->so_id` should be the last id inserted. Your code should be as below.

```
$order = new Store_order;
$order->invoice_id = $signed['invoice_id'];
$order->save();
$invoice = $order->so_id;
```

Comment: the `save()` function returns null

Comment: @MinaAbadir if the id is NOT autoincremented, this will always return 0.

Comment: Please test your code first on tinker at least. The `save()` method does not return anything. There is nothing about auto-increment here.

Comment: Actually `save()` returns boolean value either true or false what I believe. If it has successfully inserted value then `save()` returns `1` if not then `0`

Comment: It worked in Lumen 8.0 version also. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can get it by like below :

```
$order = new Store_order;
$order->invoice_id = $signed['invoice_id'];
$invoice = $order->save();
echo $invoice->so_id;
```

in this case you no need to store in one variable and then access it, You can get the inserted records by calling the model object itself :

```
    $order = new Store_order;
    $order->invoice_id = $signed['invoice_id'];
    $order->save();
    // echo $order; => will return entire stored last record.
    echo $order->so_id;
```

Make sure so_id is autoincrement.

Comment: $order->id working

Answer (score 0):

You can get the **last inserted id** by the following codes.

**Using Laravel Eloquent**

```
$order = new Store_order();
$order->invoice_id = $signed['invoice_id'];
$order->save();

$lastInsertedId = $order->so_id;     //now getting Last inserted id
echo $lastInsertedId;
```

Provided that   **$order->so_id** means last inserted id of the given object where **so_id** is the primary key of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this once it worked for me where $mode->save(); was only returning true.

```
$mylastid = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of you did overwride the name of primary key in the model as in next case:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'your_table_id_name';
```

use:

```
$id = $your_variable_save->your_table_id_name
```

if not:

```
$id = $your_variable_save->id
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$ObjTable->nane = $name;
$ObjTable->save();
echo $ObjTable->id;
```

this will be display last inserted id.