# Eloquent / Laravel: How to get last insert/update ID/instance of updateOrCreate()?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, upsert, laravel-5.5

The title is mostly self-explanatory. Eloquent has a method called

> `updateOrCreate()`

documented here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#other-creation-methods

In some cases this is really useful. However after doing `updateOrCreate()` I need either the updated/created object or its primary key or its id.

Of course I could do `MyModel::where(...)->first()` and give all those data again but this is clumsy and may be some expensive request.

However `updateOrCreate()` only returns **true** or **false**.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel, get last insert id using Eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084833/laravel-get-last-insert-id-using-eloquent)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The method will return ID of created or updated object, so just do this:

```
$object = Model::updateOrCreate(['name' => 'John'], ['age' => 25]);

$id = $object->id;
```

Comment: Actually you are right seems like I had a custom function in mind which didnt thanks.

Comment: The method seems to always return the object?

Answer (score 1):

```
$insertid = DB::table('temp_registration_master')->insertGetId($master_detail);
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score -3):

Query for the last one

```
$lastRecord = MyModel::last();
```

Or

```
$lastRecord = MyModel::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first();
```

Comment: This wouldn't always get you the right record, say you had a table of 40 rows, the updateOrCreate method updates id 20, neither of the above would return the one updated. The above would only work if it created a new record.

Comment: Yes, you're right, you'll have to use `updated_at` if you're using timestamps. Otherwise there's no other way (unless you save the id like Alexey said. I thought the question was about different requests.