# Getting the id of inserted row in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Here is my code:

```
User::create([
    'name' => $request->name,
    'email' => $request->email,
    'cell_phone' => $request->cell_phone,
    'province_id' => $request->province,
    'city_id' => $request->city,
    'job' => $job,
    'company' => $company,
    'member_num' => $member_num,
]);
```

As you know, it inserts a new row in the database. Now I need to get the `id` of inserted row. How can I get that?

---

Noted that I know, [I can do the same if I use `$obj->save()`, and the id will be `$obj->id;`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21084888/2805376). But I want to know how can I do that when I'm using `create()`.

Comment: $userDetials  = User::create([
    'name' => $request->name,
    'email' => $request->email,
    'cell_phone' => $request->cell_phone,
    'province_id' => $request->province,
    'city_id' => $request->city,
    'job' => $job,
    'company' => $company,
    'member_num' => $member_num,
]);

Comment: which version of Laravel you're talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get user inserted id using code

```
$userDetials = User::create([
     'name' => $request->name,
     'email' => $request->email,
     'cell_phone' => $request->cell_phone,
     'province_id' => $request->province,
     'city_id' => $request->city,
     'job' => $job,
     'company' => $company,
     'member_num' => $member_num,
]);
if(isset($userDetials->id))    
{
    //if inserted 
    return $userDetials->id;
}
else
{
   //not inserted
}
```

> The **create** method returns the saved model instance

Comment: @stack Welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

[As per the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent)

> The create method returns the saved model instance:

In your case it would be

```
$user = User::create(...)
```

Comment: I see, thank you, upvote. Just can you please tell me how can I check was inserted successfully? I mean is it correct? `if( isset($user->id) ){ /* row inserted */ }`

Comment: @stack you can check it using like `if($user instance of User){...}` check if  $user is an instance of your model

Comment: it returns the model instance regardless of whether `save` was successful or not

Comment: @lagbox then you can use isset also and `if($user->id){...}`

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = User::create([
      'name' => $request->name,
      'email' => $request->email,
      'cell_phone' => $request->cell_phone,
      'province_id' => $request->province,
      'city_id' => $request->city,
      'job' => $job,
      'company' => $company,
      'member_num' => $member_num,
]);
```

After `create`, `$data->id` should be the last id inserted.

```
return Response::json(array('success' => true, 'last_insert_id' => $data->id), 200);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here `create` and `save` both method returns last generated id but make sure you are make the field auto increment.

```
$userobj = User::create([
'name' => $request->name,
'email' => $request->email,
'cell_phone' => $request->cell_phone,
'province_id' => $request->province,
'city_id' => $request->city,
'job' => $job,
'company' => $company,
'member_num' => $member_num,
]);
echo $userobj->id;
```

if you want to use create method you have to define all the fields as a fillable in you model, and save() method used in both for create and edit so habit of using save method is good,

example of save method

```
 $user = User::first();
 $user->email = 'updated@domain.com';
 $user->save();
echo $user->id;
```

both method returns last inserted id.
i hope it helps,
Thank you...

Comment: Wel come and thnks :)