# Laravel 5.5: Getting id after insert

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a model hotel.php to insert hotel data.insert data using create() but it dosen't return id, the returning collection hasn't id field!

> **Controller.php**

```
/** "/user/2/create" */        
public function store(User $user, HotelRequest $request) 
        { 

            $slug = (new hotel)->uniqueSlug( $request->name );

            $request->merge([ 
                    'cat_id' => 1,
                    'slug' => $slug,
                    'created_by' => auth()->user()->id,
                ]); 

            $hotel = $user->hotels()->create( $request->all() ); 
            dd($hotel);
    ................
```

> **hotel.php (model)**

```
    namespace App;
    use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class hotel extends Model
    {
        protected $fillable = ['name', 'description','address','street','city','email',
'phone','web','cat_id','slug','created_by'];

        protected  $primaryKey = 'slug'; 

        /** 
            unique slugs genarating
        */
        protected $slug_guards = ['create','room'];

        public $incrementing = false;
```

> **User.php (model)**

```
public function hotels( )
{
    return $this->hasmany('App\Hotel');
}
```

and the final result
[image]

It dosen't have id attribute. I need id to upload image!

NB: I changed that primarykey to default 'id' but no change in result.
[image]

> **Create_hotels... migration**

```
public function up() 
{
    Schema::create('hotels', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->integer('created_by');
        $table->integer('cat_id');
        $table->string('name');
```

Comment: Do you have an id column in your table?

Comment: yes ofcurz and its incrementing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel, get last insert id using Eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084833/laravel-get-last-insert-id-using-eloquent)

Answer (score 1):

Your hotel model set the primary key as the slug :

```
    protected  $primaryKey = 'slug';
```

What i usually do, is for all my migrations, i set an autoincrements like following :

```
$table->increments('id');
```

this way laravel handles everything for you. Each create, update or whatever method handle the id of your items.

With this, you can then return the id of a stored data this way :

```
$id = create($data)->id;
```

where `$data` is your model with new datas. `$id` should now contain the `id` value of the newest stored model datas.

Comment: `$hotel = $user->hotels()->create( $request->all() ); 

            dd($hotel->id);`  result is `null`

Comment: `$hotel = $user->hotels()->create( $request->all() )->id`

Comment: Ahh.. still returning `null`

Comment: Did you refresh your migrations using `php artisan migrate:refresh` after adding the `$table->increments('id');` line?

Comment: then if there is no other way, request it again, even if it's dirty and really weird : `Hotels::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();`

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the `Hotel` model (or remove the whole line):

```
public $incrementing = true;
```

Comment: yah. i did that i commented it out.. but still not working

Comment: And set `protected  $primaryKey = 'id'; `?

Answer (score 0):

You are dumping the data you just inserted into the db which does not contain a id field.

create a show method in your Controller class as follows

```
public function show(User $user){
    dd($user)
}
```

with a route as follows:

```
Route::get('user/{user}', 'Controller@show')
```

Comment: Ah... noo when I'm trying this methods in other controller its working... i dumped after creating. So that should be contain an id field.. the other models do.

Answer (score 0):

In `hotel.php` before the `protected $fillable` declaration try adding

```
protected $guarded = [
    'id',
];
```

In your controllers `store()` method just after `$slug = (new hotel)->uniqueSlug( $request->name );`

try adding a `$slug->save();` then returned slug should have an `ID` returned with it.

and/or possible the same similar strategy after line

`$hotel = $user->hotels()->create( $request->all() );`

by adding `$hotel->save();`

Comment: AH.. the slug field not in separate table

Answer (score 0):

I changed the primarykey to default `id` and `$incrementing = true;` now its returning `id` of the created data. I changed whole methodes in Controller