# Grabbing userID and field upon user creation

Tags: php, laravel

I currently have a function that simply creates a user record in the database

```
$user->name;
$user->address;
$user->save();
```

Once this is done, I've created an id for them in my users table.

I know I can return $user, but specifically how can I grab the id and name from that to be used in a call like so:

```
$user->save();

//return $user id and $user name
$update = new UpdateTable($id,$name);
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084833/get-the-last-inserted-id-using-laravel-eloquent ?

Answer (score 6):

When you call `$user->save()`, the `id` (or primary key if it is not `id`) becomes available via `$user->id`. So, you'd simply pass the following to your `UpdateTable()` method:

```
$user = new User();

$user->name = "Test";
$user->address = "123 Somewhere";

$user->save();

$update = new UpdateTable($user->id, $user->name);
...
```

Comment: ok I tried that but it's not working. After the save, I'm dumping the user which gives objects with fillable, attributes, and original. Attributes and original both have the fields I need.

Comment: `dd($user)` (dump and die) should only show 1 `User` model, not multiple objects. `attributes` and `original` are properties of the `Model`, which can be access via `$model->{attribute}`, or in this case `$user->id`, etc. When you say "but it's not working", what, *specifically* isn't working? Are you getting an error?

Comment: No error, but the update that I'm calling isn't actually updating. So as long as I'm doing it right from here, then I'll try again

Comment: It's likely something inside your `UpdateTable` logic. After save, if you do a `dd($user->id)`, or `dd($user->name)` you should get a value. So, moving forward, if you experience a new problem, it's best to ask a new question.

Comment: Ah I realized after dumping them that the id is an int but the name is a string and I was passing both as strings

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$user = User::create(['name' => 'name', 'address' => 'Some address']);
$update = new UpdateTable($user->id, $user->name);
```

or

```
$update = new UpdateTable($user->getPrimaryKey(), $user->name);
```

Comment: mention about the fillable attributes as well.