# How can i get the id of the user i just added in a store function() Larevel 6.0

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

***I did a register of users in my own controller, i want the id of the user i just added because i want to use it in another table in that same controller and function***

- Below i will let the code of how i tried but doesn't work i want to know how could i do that
- I want something like this `$usuario->fk_cliente_natural=$cliente_natural->id_cliente_natural;` but sais that `$cliente_natural->id_cliente_natural` is null because i dont get the last id

***Code of my `store function()`***

```php
   public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $cliente_natural=new Cliente_natural();
        $cliente_natural->primer_nombre=$request->primer_nombre;
        $cliente_natural->segundo_nombre=$request->segundo_nombre;
        $cliente_natural->primer_apellido=$request->primer_apellido;
        $cliente_natural->segundo_apellido=$request->segundo_apellido;
        $cliente_natural->cedula=$request->cedula;
        $cliente_natural->rif=$request->rif;
        $cliente_natural->numero_carnet=$request->numero_carnet;

        $usuario=new Usuario();
        $this->validate(request(), [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:8',
        ]);
        $cliente_natural->save();
        $usuario->email=$request->email;
        $usuario->password=$request->password;
        $usuario->fk_rol=3;
        $usuario->fk_cliente_natural=$cliente_natural->id_cliente_natural;
        //$cliente_natural->fk_lugar=getMunicipio();

        $usuario->save();

        return view('home.home2');
    }
```

***Code of my `create function()`***

```php
public function create()
    {
        $cliente_natural = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT id_cliente_natural,rif, numero_carnet,cedula,primer_nombre,
                                                segundo_nombre,primer_apellido,segundo_apellido,fk_lugar,password,
                                                email,fk_rol,id_usuario,fk_cliente_natural
                                            FROM cliente_natural,usuario"
                                        ));
        return view('auth.register')->with('cliente_natural',$cliente_natural);
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the Last Inserted Id Using Laravel Eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084833/get-the-last-inserted-id-using-laravel-eloquent)

Comment: `$cliente_natural->YOUR_PRIMARY_KEY` returns the `id` or whatever name you gave to your primary key column of the data you just added.

Comment: `$cliente_natural->id_cliente_natural` that is my id but i dont know why when i do `$usuario->fk_cliente_natural=$cliente_natural->id_cliente_natural;` said that is null

Comment: what if you `dd($usuario)`?

Comment: Said this` #attributes: array:4 [▼
    "email" => "moimarailla1998@hotmail.com"
    "password" => "12345678"
    "fk_rol" => 3
    "fk_cliente_natural" => null
  ] `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***This is how i solve it***

```php
//$usuario->fk_cliente_natural = $cliente_natural->id_cliente_natural;

$checkT = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT id_cliente_natural as id from cliente_natural WHERE rif = '$cliente_natural->rif' AND numero_carnet = '$cliente_natural->numero_carnet'"));
$id = $checkT[0]->id;

$usuario->fk_cliente_natural = $id;
```

Comment: Make sure to add error checking `if (isset($checkT[0]))` to make sure it was found in the db.