# How to take last added id of OctoberCMS model?

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

```
        $doc->user_id = Auth::getUser()->id;;
        $doc->type = post('type');
        $doc->list_num = post('list_num');
        $doc->ticket = post('ticket');
        $doc->contract = post('contract');
        $doc_id = $doc->save();
```

I want to take last added modele id from database. How I can do this?

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46482971/9556193

Answer (score 2):

```
...
$doc_id = $doc->save();
$doc_id  = $doc->id; //id is the primary id you set in model, default is id
```