# Laravel 8 how to replicate and get id of new model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm using laravel and I would like to replicate some data. So I did that :

```
$id = $request->id;
$data = Setting::find($id);
$newSetting = $data->replicate()->save();
```

But how to get the `id` of `$newSetting` ? to save that return's only true and I need to return my new `id`. I tried with push in place of save but that also return's true.
I checked the documentation but I couldn't find it.

Can somebody help me please ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the Last Inserted Id Using Laravel Eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084833/get-the-last-inserted-id-using-laravel-eloquent)

Answer (score 2):

you just have to :

```
    $id = $request->id;
    $data = Setting::find($id);
    // now replicate data and save
     $newData = $data->replicate();
   //save the new data
     $newData->save();
     //get the new id
    $newId = $newData->id;
```

Comment: Doesn't work : "Attempt to read property "id" on bool"

Comment: that's strange. Can you post the error log?

Answer (score 0):

Can do this:

```
    $id = $request->id;
    $data = Setting::find($id);
    // replicate
    $replicatedData = $data->replicate();
    // get convert the model collection to array
    $arrayReplicatedData $replicatedData->toArray();
    //save it with the create method
    $newCreatedModel = Setting::create($arrayReplicatedData);
    // Get the new id
    $newId = $newCreatedModel->id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the breakdown of how you can duplicate your record(instance) by using **replicate()** eloquent method:

1. Using **find()**:

   ```php
       $id = $request->id;
       $post = Post::find($id);
       $duplicated_post = $post->replicate();

       //you can update some fields, like:
       $duplicated_post->user_id = '2'; // newly id
       $duplicated_post->save();
   ```
2. Using **where()** clause:

   ```php
       $id = $request->id;
       $post = Post::where('id', $id)->first();
       $duplicated_post = $post->replicate();
       //you can update some fields, like:
       $duplicated_post->user_id = '2'; // newly id
       $duplicated_post->save();
   ```
3. Duplicate a relational model:

   ```php
       $id = $request->id;
       $post = Post::find($id);
       $duplicated_post = $post->replicate();
       $duplicated_post->save();

       // duplicate a user in this instance:
       $original_user = $post->users; // 'users' is the relationship between user and the post
       $new_user = $original_user->replicate();
       $new_user->name = 'John Doe'; // if you want update a name
       $new_user->save();
   ```